# How to check whether a String value is in array or not using swift

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

I tried this:

```
var array = ["led","zepp","jimmy","page"]

if array.contains("jimmy") { // error : [String] does not have a member named 'contains' .
    print("yes")
}
```

What is the syntax for the `[String]` type array?

Comment: Your syntax is correct for Swift 2.  For Swift 1.2, `if contains(array, "jimmy")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on version of swift... in 1.2:

```
    var array = ["led","zepp","jimmy","page"]
    if find(array, "jimmy") != nil {
        println("yay")
    }
```

in swift 2

```
   var array = ["led","zepp","jimmy","page"]
    if array.indexOf("jimmy") != nil {
        print("yay")
    }
```